# How can I put gray background over elements?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

his is a screenshot of the localhost webpage:

[faulty image removed]

This is a screenshot of the deployed webpage with vercel:

[image: This is a screenshot of the deployed webpage with vercel]

The problem is that the gray div shows its underlying elements.

```css
.zoombackground {
  background-color: #333;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 9999999999999999999999999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Everything is fine when I am working with the localhost but the deployed webpage does look different and there aren't any deployment failures

Comment: Please revise your post to fix the faulty image and add HTML to the demo I created. We don't debug images here. See [ask].

Comment: I suspect that `z-index: 9999999999999999999999999 !important;` may cause issues, as integers typically cannot be that large. Also it should be obvious that this is not how z-index is meant to be used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(Assuming you're trying to make it so the color grey covers those images)
I would definitely suggest changing the format of what you're trying to do. You're using a background as a foreground, and trying to keep the elements below that foreground visible at all times. I would instead recommend making the elements in the div hidden until you want them to be shown, while keeping either the div at the same size and just being grey, or making the div relatively expand when you want the images to appear